# CRTP for conditionally adding a member

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to write a CRTP class that adds a member to a class, only if a member with the same name does not exist (in C++17)?

```cpp
template<class C> using require_foo = ...;

struct Foolish : require_foo<Foolish> {
    int foo;
}; // contains just one foo, CRTP is an empty base


struct NotFoolish : require_foo<NotFoolish> {
}; // contains just one foo, provided by CRTP base
```

I tried the obvious:

```
#include <type_traits>

void has_foo_helper(...);

template<class Class>
auto has_foo_helper(Class* obj) -> decltype(obj->foo);

template<class Class>
constexpr bool has_foo =
    std::is_same_v<decltype(has_foo_helper(std::declval<Class*>())), int>;

template<class, bool>
struct require_foo_impl;

template<class Class>
struct require_foo_impl<Class, false> {
};

template<class Class>
struct require_foo_impl<Class, true> {
    int foo;
};

template<class Class>
using require_foo = require_foo_impl<Class, has_foo<Class>>;
```

...but it doesn't work:

```
static_assert(has_foo<Foolish>); // failed due to requirement 'has_foo<Foolish>'
static_assert(has_foo<NotFoolish>); // failed due to requirement 'has_foo<NotFoolish>'
```

Thinking about it, `has_foo` seems paradoxical: if a class does not have a `foo`, it adds it, but now the class has a `foo`, so it does not add it, etc.

So I am pessimistic about the existence of a solution, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: It can be done with decorator like this: https://godbolt.org/z/fPssooh66
As the answer below states, CRTP is rather out of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no solution here in C++, nor that it's likely that there will ever be one.

The fundamental issue is `Foolish` and `NotFoolish`'s definitions are not complete until their closing brace, and they need to inherit from a superclass that needs to have a complete definition of the class that inherits from it. Without a complete definition it's not possible to determine, via CRTP, SFINAE, or any other technique, whether it has or has not a particular member. And the superclass must have a complete definition, of the superclass, before the definition of any class that inherits from it can be complete.

This chicken vs. egg problem is fundamentally unsolvable in C++.